# Inspecting proof terms in Agda

Tags: agda, user-experience

In Coq, if I am unsure how a definition `foo` is defined, I can use the command `Print foo.` to inspect what `foo` looks like. If I am not satisfied with this, I can also build a dummy goal, say `Goal foo = foo.` and then use tactics such as `unfold` to gradually unroll the definition of `foo` (say I do first `unfold foo.`, then I see another term `bar` so I can `unfold bar.`, and so forth).

Is it possible to perform a similar task in Agda? I am aware of the ability to "normalize a term" (C-c C-n), and I could also look at the source Agda definition, but in my case I would very much like to inspect the body of a definition *after* elaboration, but *before* any form of normalization.

I also considered using reflection, in particular the `getDefinition` operation, but unfortunately this gives a value of type `Definition` only under the type-checking monad, and as far as I can tell there is no direct way to inspect this value.

Comment: Note that top level pattern-matching functions are not `match` expressions like in Coq, they are their own thing, which is roughly regarded as postulated constants together with equality rules, and can't be "expanded".

Comment: You are right, there is not really an all-encompassing notion of "term" as in Coq. But as far as I can tell the "Definition" type available in meta-programming corresponds to these postulated constants, so probably this is what I want to inspect.

Answer (score 2):

1. What are you meaning by elaboration in this context? If you just want macros to be expanded, then `C-c C-m` will do what you want: you can give a term, and it will elaborate it (without normalizing it) and use it to fill the given hole. You might need to refine afterwards, I can't remember.
2. To print TC values, you can use the [debugPrint function](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Agda.Builtin.Reflection.html#10141), or for more heavy-duty things, you can use the [Reflection external interface](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Reflection.External.html) to e.g. write terms to files or do other logging. For either of these you probably want to use the functions in [Reflection.AST.Show](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Reflection.AST.Show.html)

Comment: Basically, I have a top-level definition `foo` and I want to look at what the corresponding `Definition` built by Agda from it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-answer. Compile the `master-sexp` branch of my [Agda s-expression extension](https://github.com/andrejbauer/agda/tree/master-sexp), run agda with `--sexp` option and enjoy the glory of the internal representation in the generated `.sexp` file. (In Emacs, `pp-buffer` is your friend.)